# "I'm a large." (Seinfeld)

Tags: meaning-in-context

[The Label Maker](http://www.imsdb.com/transcripts/Seinfeld-The-Label-Maker.html):

> JERRY: Why'd you get him a gift anyway?
>
> ELAINE: Oh, he did some dental work for me and he didn't charge me so I thought I'd get him a Christmas present.
>
> JERRY: Yeah, well, if you're getting him anything for his birthday, **I'm a large**.

The context is that  Elaine had given a present to a guy and then that guy "re-gifted" it to Jerry. What does this *I'm a large* mean?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It's a clothing size.  He wears a large.  His joke anticipates clothing, given as a gift, being re-gifted to Jerry.

Comment: Wow! This is fast... and of course, correct. :-)

Comment: I would also clarify that this is most likely T-shirt (or other type of shirt) clothing size, as opposed to pants or undergarments.

Comment: Good and quick answer! The only odd thing about this, then, is that Jerry is a large. He seems more like a medium?

Comment: +1 I'd have spent more than a day understanding this ;) Great snailplane!

Comment: @thomax: That's true. But maybe the script writers thought that 'I'm a medium' might be ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

He is insinuating that since he is getting a present, he should also and then says indirectly, "and when you buy me a present I need size Large.

Comment: Not exactly. The other guy gave the last present to Jerry. Jerry hopes that next time he will get the guy's present again, so he is asking Elaine to buy it in his size.