# "Your clothes are small size" --- Is this grammatical?

Tags: adjectives, word-order, spoken-english, adjective-phrases

I am having trouble with this sentence:

> ***Your clothes are small size.***

Would it be correct if I changed it to either:

> 1) Your clothes are **small-sized**. (=adjective)
>
> 2) Your clothes are **small in size**. (=adjective + prep +noun)

Comment: Related questions:  [“I'm a large.” (Seinfeld)](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/20315), [What does the preposition “in” in “I’m looking for a sweater in a size medium” mean?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/192914), [“Grow out of clothes”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/204525)

Answer (score 5):

Both of the original poster's suggested corrections are grammatically and semantically correct.  #2 ("small in size") is an idiomatic expression, but is not usually used to describe clothes.  #1 is not an idiomatic expression.  The following options are natural in American English:

> 3) Your clothes are size "Small".
>
> 4) Your clothes are all Smalls.
>
> 5) Your clothes are small.
>
> 6) Your clothes are too small.

Option #3 probably means what the original poster intends.  The quotation marks are optional.

Option #4 means that all of "your clothes" are size Small.  (Out of options #3 - 6, option #4 is the least natural.)  In the United States, many clothing products are sold in a series of sizes:  Small, Medium, and Large.  There can also be "Extra Small", "Extra Large", "Extra Extra Large", *et cetera*.  These sizes (from smallest to largest) are abbreviated XS, S, M, L, XL, XXL or 2XL, *et cetera*.  The abbreviation "XXL" or "2XL" is often pronounced "Double XL".

Option #5 is ambiguous.  It could mean the same thing as option #3, or it could mean the same thing as option #6.

Option #6 means that your clothes (no matter what size they started out as) are too small for you.  Perhaps you bought the wrong size clothes, or perhaps your clothes "shrank in the wash", or perhaps you grew taller, or perhaps you gained weight.